# Kirschenhofer Ramanujan functional equations

Tags: calculus

Ramanujan analyzed 
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{e^{-k x}}{e^{-2 k x}+1}=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\pi  \operatorname{sech}\left(\frac{\pi ^2 k}{x}\right)}{2 x}+\frac{\pi }{4 x}-\frac{1}{4}$$

it is possible to show the following identity,numerically it seem equal
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\pi  \csc \left(\frac{\pi  (x+2 i \pi  n)}{4 x}\right) \sec \left(\frac{\pi  (x+2 i \pi  n)}{4 x}\right)}{4 x}=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\pi  \operatorname{sech}\left(\frac{\pi ^2 k}{x}\right)}{2 x}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$\csc\left(\frac{\pi\left(x+2\pi in\right)}{4x}\right)\sec\left(\frac{\pi\left(x+2\pi in\right)}{4x}\right)=
 $$ $$=\frac{2i}{e^{i\pi/4-\pi^{2}n/\left(2x\right)}-e^{-i\pi/4+\pi^{2}n/\left(2x\right)}}\frac{2}{e^{i\pi/4-\pi^{2}n/\left(2x\right)}+e^{-i\pi/4+\pi^{2}n/\left(2x\right)}}=
 $$ $$=\frac{4i}{e^{i\pi/2-\pi^{2}n/x}-e^{-i\pi/2+\pi^{2}n/x}}=\frac{4}{e^{-\pi^{2}n/x}+e^{\pi^{2}n/x}}=
 $$ $$=2\textrm{sech}\left(\frac{\pi^{2}n}{x}\right).
 $$